# What does the gray line in the progress bar mean

Tags: support, review, user-interface, badges

[image]

Here is the screenshot above, what does that gray line in the progress bar mean? I have been able to find neither proper meta post(s) nor documentation reference. But I bet the question is general for the  the whole SA sites, not just math side. So feel free to move it away/mark it as a dup if an appropriate answer exists.

P.S. to be clear: the screenshot was taken in the "review" tab

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It marks the 250 review tasks necessary to be awarded the [Reviewer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/157/reviewer) badge, whereas the full bar represents what you need to get the [Steward](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/228/steward) badge.